# Cкрытые поля, конструкторы с параметрами и без параметров, методы, свойства класса

Tags: c#

Помогите дополнить программу (программа рабочая). Каждый разрабатываемый класс должен, как правило, содержать следующие элементы: скрытые поля, конструкторы с параметрами и без параметров, методы, свойства. Сам не пойму что есть что. Заранее спасибо!

```
using System;

class Vector
{
    public Vector(double x1, double y1, double z1)
    {
        X = x1;
        Y = y1;
        Z = z1;
    }
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public double Length()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
    }
    public static Vector operator +(Vector l, Vector r)
    {
        return new Vector(l.X + r.X, l.Y + r.Y, l.Z + r.Z);
    }
    public static Vector operator -(Vector l, Vector r)
    {
        return new Vector(l.X - r.X, l.Y - r.Y, l.Z - r.Z);
    }
    public static double operator *(Vector l, Vector r)
    {
        return (l.X * r.X + l.Y * r.Y + l.Z * r.Z);
    }
    public static double Cos(Vector l, Vector r)
    {
        return (l * r) / (l.Length() * r.Length());
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0},{1},{2})", X, Y, Z);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // начальные коодинаты 1-го вектора
        Console.Write("Введите значение х1 вектора а: ");
        double xx1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение y1 вектора а: ");
        double yy1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение z1 вектора а: ");
        double zz1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        // конечные коодинаты 1-го вектора
        Console.Write("Введите значение х2 вектора а: ");
        double xx11 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение y2 вектора а: ");
        double yy11 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение z2 вектора а: ");
        double zz11 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        // начальные коодинаты 2-го вектора
        Console.Write("Введите значение х1 вектора b: ");
        double xx2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение y1 вектора b: ");
        double yy2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение z1 вектора b: ");
        double zz2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        // конечные коодинаты 2-го вектора
        Console.Write("Введите значение х2 вектора b: ");
        double xx22 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение y2 вектора b: ");
        double yy22 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите значение z2 вектора b: ");
        double zz22 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        //input
        Vector v1 = new Vector(xx11 - xx1, yy11 - yy1, zz11 - zz1);
        Vector v2 = new Vector(xx22 - xx2, yy22 - yy2, yy22 - yy2);
        Vector v3 = v1 + v2;
        Vector v4 = v1 - v2;
        double m = v1 * v2;
        double c = Vector.Cos(v1, v2);
        double len1 = v1.Length();
        double len2 = v2.Length();
        int test = 0;
        //exeption
        try
        {
            len1 = v1.Length();
            len2 = v2.Length();

            if (len1 == 0 || len2 == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Вектор не может быть нулевым");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nОшибка: " + e.Message);
            test = 10;
        }

        //output
        if (test != 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Вектор a: ");
            Console.WriteLine(v1);
            Console.Write("Вектор б: ");
            Console.WriteLine(v2);
            Console.Write("Вектор а+б: ");
            Console.WriteLine(v3);
            Console.Write("Вектор а-б: ");
            Console.WriteLine(v4);
            Console.Write("Вектор а*б: ");
            Console.WriteLine(m);
            Console.Write("Косинус угла между векторами a и б: ");
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.Write("Длина вектора 1: ");
            Console.WriteLine(len1);
            Console.Write("Длина вектора 2: ");
            Console.WriteLine(len2);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: А что вам надо добавить, если у вас все работает?

Comment: А какую реальную проблему вы решаете? Или это лабораторная работа, бессмысленная и беспощадная?

Comment: Это лабораторная работа, бессмысленная и беспощадная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильней, внутренние переменные делать скрытые, и обращаться к ним через свойства или методы. 
Поэтому поменяйте public переменные на private:

```
private double _x;
private double _y;
private double _z;
```

[Конструктор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173115.aspx) с параметром у Вас есть:

`public Vector(double x1, double y1, double z1)`

Теперь можно добавить конструктор без параметров, например:

```
public Vector()
{
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    Z = 0;
}
```

Методы у Вас есть, например:

```
public double Length();
```

Теперь можно написать [свойство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), для работы с закрытыми переменными _x, _y, _z.

```
public double X
{
    get { return _x; }
    set { _x = value; }
}
```

Аналогично пишем, для остальных переменных _y, _z.

Answer (score 2):

В справке от Microsoft все хорошо расписано. [Классы в С#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9afc042.aspx)

В вашем случае:

Конструктор с параметрами: 
 `public Vector(double x1, double y1, double z1)` 

Публичные поля: 
`public double X; public double Y; public double Z;`

Методы:

 `public double Length()` 
Переопределение операторов: `public static Vector operator +(Vector l, Vector r)` 
Описание перегружаемых операторов: [сслыка](http://%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)